# Omitted code blocks from clang AST for ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I was generating AST for Objective C code on a .m file 
The command is roughly like `clang-check -ast-dump /source/file.m &> /output/file.txt`

It had an error that said

```
Error while trying to load a compilation database: Could not auto-detect compilation database for file '/source/file.m' 

No compilation database found in /source or any parent directory 

json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory

Running without flags.

In file included from /source .. fatal error:'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
```

I'm not sure if it's related to the error thrown above, but many of my CompoundStmt blocks are empty. If they contain C or C++ code then they are reflected in the CompoundStmt, but not when it contains code like `NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from peopleInfo where peopleInfoID=%d, self.recordIDToEdit]` or even `NSString *abc = "ABC"`

Comment: did you manage to make this work? I'm getting an error even after generating the compile commands files. 
```fatal error: no handler registered for module format 'obj'
LLVM ERROR: unknown module format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate something called a compilation database. For Clang it will be a json file (default name: compile_commands.json)

You can read about it [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html).

> Tools based on the C++ Abstract Syntax Tree need full information how
>   to parse a translation unit. Usually this information is implicitly
>   available in the build system, but running tools as part of the build
>   system is not necessarily the best solution.
>
> A compilation database is a JSON file, which consist of an array of
>   “command objects”, where each command object specifies one way a
>   translation unit is compiled in the project.

A sample json file will look like:

```
[
  {
    "directory": "/source",
    "command": "clang++ <file>.m",
    "file": "/source/div0.c"
  }
]
```

You can read [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html) and [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/05/21/compilation-databases-for-clang-based-tools) on how to setup a compilation database.