# Running clang static checker at project level (iOS app) rather than file by file (xcodebuild)

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, xcodebuild, clang-static-analyzer

After solving this [Omitted code blocks from clang AST for ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875881/omitted-code-blocks-from-clang-ast-for-objectivec), I've tried it on a small Objective C .m file along with an appropriate compile_commands.json and it works properly and I get the entire syntax tree.

Now I'm trying to see if it's possible to run it on the entire xcodebuild

```
[
  {
    "directory" : "/Users/xx/Desktop/iOSApplication",
    "command" : "xcodebuild clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=\"\" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -project /Users/xx/Desktop/iOSApplication/iOSApplication.xcodeproj/",
    "file" : "iOSApplication.xcodeproj"
  }
]
```

When I tried to then run `clang-check -ast-dump /Users/xx/Desktop/iOSApplication/iOSApplication.xcodeproj` it gives me the errors `error: unknown argument: '-project'` and `error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''`

Is it actually possible to run the AST based checker on the entire xcodeproject? Or how should I go about compiling the files 1 at a time?

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to generate the compile_commands.json by following this guide here http://docs.oclint.org/en/stable/guide/xcodebuild.html

However, I'd still like to be able to run my RecursiveASTVisitor on the entire projects. Or alternatively, pass in the xcode project and enumerate all the source files would probably work too.

Anyone has ideas how to go about passing entire xcodebuild project as parameter for RecursiveASTVisitor?

Right now I'm running my ASTVisitor like this `./MyASTChecker ~/Desktop/directory/sample1.m` but I'd like to make it do something like `./MyASTChecker ~/Desktop/directory/sampleproject.xcodeproj`

Answer (score -1):

The way I do it is at compile time using scan-build. This works for me with cmake/make based projects.

```
scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker <checker_name> make
```

This will read the makefile and build everything in there while running the specified checker on each file as it's compiled. If you only want to build with some flags or a specific target, you can do this:

```
scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker <checker_name> make <build_options>
```

If you instead have a cmake based project. You might first want to generate a makefile in a build directory. I do this for that:

```
cmake <path_to_cmakelists> -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=c++-analyzer -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER=ccc-analyzer
```

This followed by scan-build from above will compile and run checker on the source files while each file is being compiled.

I have only tried this with CMAKE / MAKE but should work with xcode like this:

```
scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker <checker_name> xcodebuild
```

and with build options

```
scan-build --use-analyzer=clang -enable-checker <checker_name> xcodebuild <build_options>
```

You can read more about scan-build [here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html)

Comment: This is for using clang static analyzer? I've tried this before but now I'm working with RecursiveASTVisitor

Comment: My bad, for Recursive AST builder you can just write a compile_commands.json with all the file entries. `[{<entry for file one>, <entry for file two>},...]` To automagically generate this json file, I have used cmake with CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS flag on. I am sure xcode will have something similar.